# Why cannot the JVM auto expand heap memory to the configured Xmx3072m in linux & jdk1.6.0_32, and FullGC occurs very frequently

Tags: linux, garbage-collection, jvm

Why the JVM memory cannot auto expand to Xmx3072m in linux & jdk1.6.0_32?

The Tenured generation is used 99% and lend the FullGC very frequence. The java process is using only 1G memory, as can be seen in the output of `top`.

If we change the JVM parameters to `-Xms3072m -Xmx3072m`, then it works fine. But if we use `-Xms256m -Xmx3072m`, then the problem appears, and FullGC occurs very frequently.

These 2 params are also default:

```
MinHeapFreeRatio    40
MaxHeapFreeRatio    70
```

The environment is:

```
OS: 

Linux linux-wgvb 2.6.16.60-0.54.5-smp #1 SMP Fri Sep 4 01:28:03 UTC 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux 

JDK version: 

java version "1.6.0_32" 
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_32-b05) 
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.7-b02, mixed mode) 

JVM params: 

-Xms256m -Xmx3072m  -XX:+UseParallelOldGC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=1000
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=5 -Xrs -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

FullGC is executed frequently:

```
@linux> ./jstat -gcutil 18261 1000 500 

   S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT   
 0.00  64.67   7.04  99.53  71.89  18293  510.574  1167 1616.594 2127.168 
91.78   7.91 100.00  99.53  72.00  18299  510.821  1167 1616.594 2127.415 
77.49   0.00   0.00  99.99  72.00  18300  510.947  1168 1616.594 2127.541 
 0.00  99.83  25.71  99.49  71.72  18305  511.178  1168 1617.915 2129.093 
24.27   0.00  21.74  99.67  71.73  18310  511.342  1168 1617.915 2129.256 
28.57   0.00   0.00  99.83  71.73  18314  511.427  1169 1617.915 2129.342 
 0.00  29.29   0.00  99.56  71.82  18317  511.465  1169 1618.919 2130.384 
 0.00  78.85  54.96  99.56  72.05  18326  511.777  1169 1618.919 2130.696 
64.52   0.00   0.00  99.99  72.05  18328  511.920  1170 1618.919 2130.839 
 0.00  99.26   0.00  99.88  71.71  18333  512.079  1171 1620.014 2132.093 
 4.86   0.00   0.00  99.95  71.76  18338  512.255  1172 1620.957 2133.211 
80.98   0.00   0.00  99.69  71.83  18350  512.453  1172 1621.906 2134.359 
 0.00  64.48   0.00  99.85  71.83  18355  512.677  1173 1621.906 2134.583 
 0.00  99.80   0.00  99.93  71.71  18359  512.876  1174 1623.264 2136.139 
 0.06   0.04 100.00  99.55  71.71  18360  512.876  1174 1624.193 2137.069 
60.35   0.00   0.00  99.90  71.77  18376  513.429  1175 1624.193 2137.622 
60.35   0.00   0.00  99.90  71.77  18376  513.429  1175 1624.193 2137.622
89.86   0.00   0.00  99.83  71.78  18384  513.839  1176 1625.476 2139.315 
89.86   0.00   0.00  99.83  71.78  18384  513.839  1176 1625.476 2139.315 
 0.00  39.17  64.41  99.60  71.78  18394  514.202  1176 1626.880 2141.082 
99.93   0.00   0.00  99.82  71.78  18396  514.326  1177 1626.880 2141.206 
 0.00  64.68   0.00  99.61  71.72  18401  514.409  1177 1627.945 2142.354
```

The java process only used 1G memory:

```
   PID USER     PR  NI    VIRT  RES  SHR  S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+  COMMAND
 18261 ouser    15   0   4353m 1.0g  52m  S   325  3.2  271:25.52  java
```

```
./jstat -gccapacity 18261 1000 500
 NGCMN    NGCMX     NGC     S0C   S1C       EC      OGCMN      OGCMX       OGC         OC      PGCMN    PGCMX     PGC       PC     YGC    FGC 
 87360.0 1048576.0 136256.0 65984.0 68096.0     64.0   174784.0  2097152.0   785664.0   785664.0  65536.0 524288.0  65792.0  65792.0 141612  8100
 87360.0 1048576.0 122816.0 61376.0 12992.0     64.0   174784.0  2097152.0   791360.0   791360.0  65536.0 524288.0  65792.0  65792.0 141616  8100
 87360.0 1048576.0 115264.0 57600.0 7872.0     64.0   174784.0  2097152.0   791936.0   791936.0  65536.0 524288.0  65792.0  65792.0 141617  8101
 87360.0 1048576.0 112576.0 54912.0 56256.0     64.0   174784.0  2097152.0   797952.0   797952.0  65536.0 524288.0  65792.0  65792.0 141618  8102
 87360.0 1048576.0 112576.0 54912.0 56256.0     64.0   174784.0  2097152.0   797952.0   797952.0  65536.0 524288.0  65792.0  65792.0 141618  8102
 87360.0 1048576.0 105408.0 52672.0  192.0     64.0   174784.0  2097152.0   804096.0   804096.0  65536.0 524288.0  65792.0  65792.0 141621  8103
 87360.0 1048576.0  87360.0 35584.0 38464.0   8064.0   174784.0  2097152.0   805568.0   805568.0  65536.0 524288.0  65792.0  65792.0 141629  8103
 87360.0 1048576.0 111168.0 39488.0 46080.0  12416.0   174784.0  2097152.0   805568.0   805568.0  65536.0 524288.0  65792.0  65792.0 141635  8103
 87360.0 1048576.0 142848.0 69440.0 70592.0   1664.0   174784.0  2097152.0   805568.0   805568.0  65536.0 524288.0  65792.0  65792.0 141644  8104
 87360.0 1048576.0 142848.0 69440.0 70592.0   1664.0   174784.0  2097152.0   805568.0   805568.0  65536.0 524288.0  65792.0  65792.0 141644  8104
 87360.0 1048576.0  87360.0 35136.0 37376.0  10304.0   174784.0  2097152.0   769280.0   769280.0  65536.0 524288.0  65792.0  65792.0 141661  8105
```

Comment: I do not understand why people downvote this, its a perfectly valid GC-issue question providing enough evidence about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `RES` value isn't how much memory the process is using, but how much actual RAM it uses. This doesn't include swapped pages and allocated but unmapped pages. Make sure you have enough free memory on the system itself, you can run `free`, or even `top` should print above how much memory is in use. The output of `top` suggests that the process has 4G of memory mapped, but not currently in the RAM (the `VIRT` value).

Comment: But why if we change the JVM parameters to -Xms3072m -Xmx3072m, then it works fine. and if we use -Xms256m -Xmx3072m, then the problem appears, and FullGC occurs very frequently?

Comment: Is there RAM available or not? The JVM won't try to use unavailable memory unless you force it, since you'll get into swap thrashing, which in most cases is worse for performance than GC.

Comment: @linux-wgvb:/opt/jdk/jdk1.6.0_32/bin> free  
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached  
Mem:      32937336   28850576    4086760          0     259204   18551848
<br/>
-/+ buffers/cache:   10039524   22897812
<br/>
Swap:      2104472      32876    2071596

Comment: @linux-wgvb:/opt/jdk/jdk1.6.0_32/bin> top
top - 14:32:06 up 8 days, 22:23,  7 users,  load average: 12.30, 15.25, 16.44
Tasks: 344 total,   1 running, 343 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 35.3%us,  4.9%sy,  0.0%ni, 56.7%id,  3.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.1%si,  0.0%st
Mem:     32165M total,    28204M used,     3960M free,      253M buffers
Swap:     2055M total,       32M used,     2023M free,    18117M cached

Comment: OK, so you do have 22G free (18 with discardable cache data).

Answer (score 0):

Could you check that your `-XX:+UseAdaptiveSizePolicy` is set? It should be ON by default.

Also, you may be giving it too small `Xms` so that the GC is not able to recover and resize the heap areas in such a short time. Could you try e.g. `-Xms1024m -Xmx3072m` and `-Xms2048m -Xmx3072m`? Does GC manages to adapt the sizes properly in these cases? (Monitoring `jstat -gccapacity` on the fly would probably help here.)

In general, `UseAdaptiveSizePolicy` is helpful and the algorithm is able to adjust the Heap ergonomics. But, the main responsibility is always on the user to observe the Memory-allocation behavior of your application and set the GC parameters in its best interest. It may very well just be that `-Xms256m -Xmx3072m` is simply not good enough to keep up with your allocation rate and with the size of your live data set.

Btw. I do not think there is an issue with the system memory since the GC behaves well when you give it enough memory from the start (e.g. `-Xms3072m -Xmx3072m`).

Comment: -XX:+UseAdaptiveSizePolicy is not set in our application, it`s default value is on.

Comment: ./jstat -gccapacity 18261 1000 500 NGCMN NGCMX NGC S0C S1C EC OGCMN OGCMX OGC OC PGCMN PGCMX PGC PC YGC FGC 87360.0 1048576.0 87360.0 34688.0 32896.0 19776.0 174784.0 2097152.0 599104.0 599104.0 65536.0 524288.0 65792.0 65792.0 132576 7366

Comment: Could you sample `-gccapacity` in regular intervals, the same way you do for `-gcutil`? That way you can judge whether the `AdaptiveSizePolicy` is really effective in this scenario and whether  its changing the sizes of each area or not.

Comment: NGCMN    NGCMX     NGC     S0C   S1C       EC      OGCMN      OGCMX       OGC         OC      PGCMN    PGCMX     PGC       PC     YGC    FGC <br>
 87360.0 1048576.0 136256.0 65984.0 68096.0     64.0   174784.0  2097152.0   785664.0   785664.0  65536.0 524288.0  65792.0  65792.0 141612  8100 <br> 
 87360.0 1048576.0 122816.0 61376.0 12992.0     64.0   174784.0  2097152.0   791360.0   791360.0  65536.0 524288.0  65792.0  65792.0 141616  8100  <br> 
 87360.0 1048576.0 115264.0 57600.0 7872.0     64.0   174784.0  2097152.0   791936.0   791936.0  65536.0 524288.0  65792.0  65792.0 141617  8101

Comment: 87360.0 1048576.0 112576.0 54912.0 56256.0     64.0   174784.0  2097152.0   797952.0   797952.0  65536.0 524288.0  65792.0  65792.0 141618  8102 <br> 
 87360.0 1048576.0 112576.0 54912.0 56256.0     64.0   174784.0  2097152.0   797952.0   797952.0  65536.0 524288.0  65792.0  65792.0 141618  8102 <br> 
 87360.0 1048576.0 105408.0 52672.0  192.0     64.0   174784.0  2097152.0   804096.0   804096.0  65536.0 524288.0  65792.0  65792.0 141621  8103 <br> 
 87360.0 1048576.0  87360.0 35584.0 38464.0   8064.0   174784.0  2097152.0   805568.0   805568.0  65536.0 524288.0  65792.0  65792.0 141629  8103

Comment: 87360.0 1048576.0 111168.0 39488.0 46080.0  12416.0   174784.0  2097152.0   805568.0   805568.0  65536.0 524288.0  65792.0  65792.0 141635  8103 <br>
 87360.0 1048576.0 142848.0 69440.0 70592.0   1664.0   174784.0  2097152.0   805568.0   805568.0  65536.0 524288.0  65792.0  65792.0 141644  8104 <br>
 87360.0 1048576.0 142848.0 69440.0 70592.0   1664.0   174784.0  2097152.0   805568.0   805568.0  65536.0 524288.0  65792.0  65792.0 141644  8104 <br>
 87360.0 1048576.0  87360.0 35136.0 37376.0  10304.0   174784.0  2097152.0   769280.0   769280.0  65536.0 524288.0  65792.0  65792.0 141661  8105

Comment: Thanks but this formatting is a little messy formatting, you can just update the post and add these listings below the `-gcutil` listings. And then lets see what happens with the sizes... Btw. did you test the `-Xms1024m -Xmx3072m` options?

Comment: I have updated the -gccapacity in the content above and adjust the format

Answer (score -1):

I think you JVM command line options is currect. Maybe you have the wrong way monitoring the JVN heap.

`VIRT` is the whole space asked for by the progress, if the space is not enough, maybe swap will be used.

Maybe you can use `jstat -gccapacity 18261 1000 500` watch the statistics  of  the capacities of the generations and their corresponding spaces.

```
gc     Garbage-collected heap statistics
+-------+-------------------------------------------+
|Column |                Description                |
+-------+-------------------------------------------+
|SOC    | Current survivor space 0 capacity (KB).   |
|S1C    | Current survivor space 1 capacity (KB).   |
|S0U    | Survivor space 0 utilization (KB).        |
|S1U    | Survivor space 1 utilization (KB).        |
|EC     | Current eden space capacity (KB).         |
|EU     | Eden space utilization (KB).              |
|OC     | Current old space capacity (KB).          |
|OU     | Old space utilization (KB).               |
|PC     | Current permanent space capacity (KB).    |
|PU     | Permanent space utilization (KB).         |
|YGC    | Number of young generation GC Events.     |
|YGCT   | Young generation garbage collection time. |
|FGC    | Number of full GC events.                 |
|FGCT   | Full garbage collection time.             |
|GCT    | Total garbage collection time.            |
+-------+-------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: @linux-wgvb:/opt/jdk/jdk1.6.0_32/bin> ./jstat -gccapacity 18261 1000 500

 NGCMN    NGCMX     NGC     S0C   S1C       EC      OGCMN      OGCMX       OGC         OC      PGCMN    PGCMX     PGC       PC     YGC    FGC 
 87360.0 1048576.0  87360.0 34688.0 32896.0  19776.0   174784.0  2097152.0   599104.0   599104.0  65536.0 524288.0  65792.0  65792.0 132576  7366

Comment: It seem that OldGen occupy 585MB memory space. Only one line output say nothing.

Comment: can not write so much line here.  the other line is similar

Comment: `1000ms` is too short for changing JVM heap size. Maybe you can log the outputs enough for the changing. Otherise, mybe the heap will never reach 4G because 585MB is enough.